# nopCommerce: Using web api to change prices for one product with different options

Tags: http, asp.net-web-api, nopcommerce

I am new to nopCommerce development. I use the web api to change the data. But I do not know how I can change the prices for different sizes. There is a product with several sizes / prices.
Can someone help me?

Comment: Show us the code you made so far.

Comment: i have no Code, i make http-requests. i dont know, how to get / edit variations of a product.

Comment: @r.az91: What do you mean by * how I can change the prices for different sizes* ??

Answer (score 0):

assuming you have a grouped product as seen here http://admin-demo.nopcommerce.com/Admin/Product/Edit/13

and a simple product for all sizes and types as seen here http://admin-demo.nopcommerce.com/Admin/Product/Edit/14

in code you will need to lookup for the simple product that reflects your particular size that you want to change price, for example let say this product  http://admin-demo.nopcommerce.com/Admin/Product/Edit/14 and then you can just change the price and it will effect only for that size.

hope that answers your question.